# how to create a pdf file and download it through a nodejs application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, postgresql

I want to create a button through my nodejs application, in order to generate a file (pdf), which the client can download, the file information is filled from the postgres database.
I want help thanks

Comment: SO is not a place to ask full solutions, you need to add what you have tried so far. If you look a pdf generation module for nodejs, there are plenty, just search a bit on your favorite search engine
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use html-pdf node.js module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' }
});
```

Then you can return the link to the created file to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library or something similar to create a pdf: [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/). Then you will have to return the PDF to the client. Be sure to add the header: `'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'`.